# How to correctly read the storage changes from a contract based on stack values from debug_traceCall

Tags: evm, contract-debugging, geth-debugging, trace

I have an example structLogs from debug_traceCall

```json
        {
            "depth": 6,
            "gas": 46056236,
            "gasCost": 2900,
            "op": "SSTORE",
            "pc": 4336,
            "refund": 4800,
            "stack": [
                "0x23b872dd",
                "0x227",
                "0x9b209a6b7b943e193ea5b529483642c0db9967b8",
                "0x641c00a822e8b671738d32a431a4fb6074e5c79d",
                "0x2386f26fc10000",
                "0x0",
                "0x9f2",
                "0x9b209a6b7b943e193ea5b529483642c0db9967b8",
                "0x22d473030f116ddee9f6b43ac78ba3",
                "0x0",
                "0x22d473030f116ddee9f6b43ac78ba3",
                "0x9b209a6b7b943e193ea5b529483642c0db9967b8",
                "0x40",
                "0x20",
                "0x0",
                "0x913557f9af897f20693b0ff3d621a5e909fa774e799ffdd0505f69073478ebf7"
            ],
            "storage": {
                "360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc": "0000000000000000000000008b194beae1d3e0788a1a35173978001acdfba668",
                "8e46d941552a4c3b1a591242e49601a6d201e7c0d984fe7f21efa12bbd80cfa5": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101b0d34fe0e7adb",
                "913557f9af897f20693b0ff3d621a5e909fa774e799ffdd0505f69073478ebf7": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "94d15705f6bff62f10a25815acfbecf67ad26084447c11b4f67826708268c366": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009fbf22c7a835750c86",
                "b53127684a568b3173ae13b9f8a6016e243e63b6e8ee1178d6a717850b5d6103": "000000000000000000000000d570ace65c43af47101fc6250fd6fc63d1c22a86"
            }
        },
```

We have a list of storage data that has been changed, but I don't know which contract address's storage has changed. I want to know that.

For example : assuming this storage `360894a13ba1a3210667c828492db98dca3e2076cc3735a920a3ca505d382bbc` is belong address `0x9b209a6b7b943e193ea5b529483642c0db9967b8`